# What does $H^n(L)$ means in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

I encountered the notation $H^n(L)$ where $L$ is a line bundle over some projective variety $X$ in the book by Le Potier and some other papers. I've only seen notations like $H^n(X,L)$, so I am wondering if the notation $H^n(L)$ has any special meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there's only one space under consideration when we're talking about sheaf cohomology, it is not uncommon to omit the space when writing $H^n(X,\mathcal{F})$ and just write $H^n(\mathcal{F})$.